# Best feature selection model for large number of predictors?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I've been working with text data (26000 different tokens over 38000 rows) and I want to extract around 100 tokens to use in my final model.

My first approach was to fit a Lasso model, using all my vectorized tokens, and my depedent variable, and then selecting the best predictors, but it's taking way too long.

What approach is a good one for data with this kind of dimensionality? I would love to ideally know exactly which words I'm keeping and not get transformed, hard-to-interpret data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=boruta

Comment: "In statistics and machine learning, lasso (least absolute shrinkage and selection operator; also Lasso or LASSO) is a regression analysis **method that performs both variable selection and regularization** in order to enhance the prediction accuracy and interpretability of the statistical model it produces." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)

Comment: Random Forests are very fast and they do output feature importance. Alternatively you could use a univariate test.